# How to call functions as those?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function

I tried to download a video using this code;

```
from youtube_dl import YoutubeDL

def opts():
    url= "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ffcitRgiNDs"

    ydl_opts= {
        'format': '22'
    }
opts()

def download(url, ydl_opts):
    YoutubeDL(ydl_opts).download(url)
download()
```

And I got this error!

```
TypeError: download() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'url' and 'ydl_opts'
```

How to call fuctions like this. 'def download(url, ydl_opts)'.
Can't call 'download()'

Answer (score 0):

you can use Global variables

```py
from youtube_dl import YoutubeDL

def opts():
    global url
    url= "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ffcitRgiNDs"

    global ydl_opts
    ydl_opts= {
        'format': '22'
    }
opts()

def download(url, ydl_opts):
    YoutubeDL(ydl_opts).download(url)
download(url,ydl_opts)
```

Comment: Globals are bad, let's not encourage them.

Comment: Cant do it without global?

Comment: yeah i believe you can, its just one way to do so. depends what do you want exactly

Answer (score 0):

You are defining local variables in `opts` that don't affect the outer scope. You could use global variables (not recommended) or return values from `opts`.

```
def opts():
    url= "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ffcitRgiNDs"

    ydl_opts= {
        'format': '22'
    }
    return url, ydl_opts
```

Now you can use

```
url, ydl_opts = opts()
download(url, ydl_opts)
```

or

```
download(*opts())
```

If you want `download` to take no parameters, call `opts` in `download`.

```
def download():
    url, ydl_opts = opts()
    YoutubeDL(ydl_opts).download(url)
```